# Python only writing first line

Tags: python

I have a text file which I read in and then I extract the data I require and try sending it to a different new text file, but only the first line gets into the new text file.

```
import requests

url_file = open('url-test.txt','r')
out_file = open('url.NDJSON','w')

for url in url_file.readlines():
    html = requests.get(url).text

out_file.writelines(html)
out_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```py
for url in url_file.readlines():
    html = requests.get(url).text
    out_file.write(html)
```

or

```py
lines = []
for url in url_file.readlines():
    html = requests.get(url).text
    # verify you are getting the expected data
    print(111111, html)
    lines.append(html)
out_file.writelines(lines)
```

Comment: Still, only first-line gets back

Comment: you can add in a print statement to print the html content to verify you are getting expected result, I have updated my answer to print out the data

Answer (score 0):

either append the string in html or use the writelines statement in for loop